How do I only allow specific elements to overflow parent?
so given there's a layout that shows these 'sidenotes' – it relies on overflow: hidden not being set because they live outside of the parent element.
see the 'EXAMPLE sidenote content' in the runnable snippet below:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://edwardtufte.github.io/tufte-css/tufte.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <section>
      <p>Tufte CSS provides tools to style web articles using the ideas demonstrated by Edward Tufte’s books and handouts. Tufte’s style is known for its simplicity, extensive use of sidenotes, tight integration of graphics with text, and carefully chosen
        typography.</p>
      <p>In print, Tufte has used the proprietary Monotype Bembo<label for="sn-proprietary-monotype-bembo" class="margin-toggle sidenote-number"></label><input type="checkbox" id="sn-proprietary-monotype-bembo" class="margin-toggle"><span class="sidenote">EXAMPLE sidenote content</span>        font. A similar effect is achieved in digital formats with the now open-source <a href="https://github.com/edwardtufte/et-book">ETBook</a>, which Tufte CSS supplies with a <code>@font-face</code> reference to a .ttf file. In case ETBook somehow
        doesn’t work, Tufte CSS shifts gracefully to other serif fonts like Palatino and Georgia.</p>

    </section>

  </article>
</body>

</html>



how do i prevent everything except these "sidenotes" from overflowing? e.g. i want text to wrap, or a <pre> tag to scroll horizontally.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://edwardtufte.github.io/tufte-css/tufte.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <section>
      <p>⬇️ i'd rather this wrap or be truncated, how?</p>
      <p><a href="http://very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.large.horse/">http://very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.large.horse/</a></p>
      <p>In print, Tufte has used the proprietary Monotype Bembo<label for="sn-proprietary-monotype-bembo" class="margin-toggle sidenote-number"></label><input type="checkbox" id="sn-proprietary-monotype-bembo" class="margin-toggle"><span class="sidenote">EXAMPLE sidenote content</span>        font. A similar effect is achieved in digital formats with the now open-source <a href="https://github.com/edwardtufte/et-book">ETBook</a>, which Tufte CSS supplies with a <code>@font-face</code> reference to a .ttf file. In case ETBook somehow
        doesn’t work, Tufte CSS shifts gracefully to other serif fonts like Palatino and Georgia.</p>

    </section>

  </article>
</body>

</html>




overflow-wrap: anywhere; to p elements?

@TemaniAfif bingo - thank you!!
